# Can I use OctoPi locally?

Tags: octoprint, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use my M3D printer that doesn't work with my Linux computer. I have been told that OctoPi would make it work.

My current setup is:

- Raspberry 2 **without WiFi**, with OctoPi running
- Keyboard and touchscreen connected to the Raspberry
- A `.obj` file located in `/home/pi/` on the Raspberry

I don't know anything about OctoPi, but it seems to be created to use as a print server connected by WiFi.

My question is: how can I use it locally, directly on my Raspberry?

*NOTE:* I can only use my Raspberry in command line for the moment, but if required I can install lightdm to display stuff.

Comment: If you install a web browser on the raspberry pi, you can access octoprint from there (by going to localhost). Is this what you're after?

Comment: Have you considered maybe using wired Ethernet, the way OctoPrint was originally designed to work, as described by most Octoprint installation guides, skipping the optional WiFi setup -- [a](http://www.instructables.com/id/Newbies-guide-to-Installing-configuring-Octoprint-/), [b](http://www.akeric.com/blog/?tag=octopi), [c](http://reprap.org/wiki/OctoPrint), [d](https://learn.adafruit.com/octoprint-open-source-host-software/octopi-ready-made-octoprint-os-disk-image), etc. -- instead of WiFi? Normal wired Ethernet cables work fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use it locally you need to be able to view the desktop. 

`sudo raspi-config`  to pull up the config menu and enable boot to desktop.
If there is no browser installed already you'll need to install one.

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser`

Open the browser and navigate to http://localhost/

I recommend configuring access control when it prompts you. After you configure it, click login in the top right and login to use octopi.

**ALTERNATIVE**

[octocmd](http://octocmd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a command line interface for octoprint. If you would rather not boot into the desktop then this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the alternative. That's exactly what I was looking for.